# C# how to get response header values in mvc controller application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I  have created a web api application in .net core 6.0 and passing a header value using Redirect response and I have another MVC .net core application where I'm trying to capture the header however I'm not getting the header key.

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("Redirect")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RedirectTo()
        {
     var result = new RedirectResult("http://localhost:5239/");
                result.UrlHelper = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper(_accessor.ActionContext);

                result.UrlHelper
                      .ActionContext
                      .HttpContext
                      .Response.Redirect("http://localhost:5239/");

                result.UrlHelper
                      .ActionContext
                      .HttpContext
                      .Response.Headers.Add("Just-Token", new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues("JustToken"));

                return result;

}

// MVC controller application

public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues headerValues = "";
            var r = Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Just-Token", out headerValues); // getting null
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: When you look in browser Network tab - do you see the header? That will help you focus troubleshooting

Comment: @Felix I see it but how to get that, is my question.

Comment: shouldn't it be `Response`, rather than `Request`?

Comment: @Felix I checked both, nothing works

Comment: See following : https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Jul/07/Back-to-Basics-Custom-HTTP-Response-Header-Manipulation-in-ASPNET-Core  Should be : var headers = HttpContext.Response.Headers;

Comment: @jdweng No it's blank, I believe redirecting to another site with headers not supported

Comment: Every Request/Response can contain headers.  A request/response message is html format which can contain a header and a body. Redirecting has nothing to do with the html format of the message.

Comment: @jdweng You can try my example and check.. and I have seen an article which says it.

Comment: Can you verify the server added the headers?  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and verify the response contains headers.

Comment: @jdweng yes I can see in the network call.

Comment: I can't tell from the code posted.  You are using the Request while the link I provided is using the response HttpContext.Response.Headers.  You MUST use the response. You also must use the instance of the class and not a static method.